# Different views My Site tabs

Tags: sharepoint-designer, my-site, quick-launch

I have a situation where my company wants to create different views for different users on the tabs of My Site Quicklaunch.

The default tabs are (as we all know) Overview, My content, My Colleagues, Tags and Notes and a few more.

I want to create new tabs but the new tabs should be restricted to what kind of group the user belongs to when he/she logs in to his/hers mysite.

For instance, if user 1 belongs to group 1, user 1 should see a tab that is called My Documents. But if user 2 that belongs to group 2 loggs in, he/she should not be able to see the tab My Documents.

I have tried making the custom tabs audience targeted, but that doesn't work. All users, no matter what group they belong to can still see all tabs.

I've heard that you can use SPSecurityTrimmedControl, but I have no idea how to use it in Mysite with permissions.

Can anyone help me, please? :)

// Johanna

Answer (score 1):

The My Site tabs which you want to customize are part of the "GlobalNavigationControl" Delegate Control. You will have to Create your own Custom Delegate Control with the security logic built inside it and deploy it using a feature.

Here is a detailed walk-through on customizing My Sites Navigation:

[Customizing My Sites in Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spsocial/archive/2010/03/30/customizing-my-sites-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2010.aspx)